# jQuery markingup! and IE error on certain pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, markitup

I have an app that uses jQuery 1.4.4 with latest markitup! extension.

I have no problems with Firefox, everything works.
But IE (in my case IE8) is giving me some real headache.

I have a textbox input that I combine with markitup!. I have the same JS and CSS code linked to in both the admin side of the application and the client side.

The client side textbox works just fine and I see the markitup bar above it just fine.
The same code produces an error in IE on the admin side and does not display markitup! bar above the msg box. I have removed all other JS file references in the admin section to ensure no conflicts. But it still does not work and I get JS error in IE.

Here's what I have included on both pages (down to the bare necessities):

```
jquery-1.4.4.min.js
jquery.markitup.min.js
jquery.markitup.settings.js
custom.js

// ----- custom.js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("textarea#message_body").markItUp(markitupTextileSettings);
});
```

So the above code works 100% fine in Firefox in both client and admin. And what is really bizarre is the same code works in IE8 on client side pages, but does not work in the admin-side section.

I get the following error

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MDDC; .NET4.0C; Tablet PC 2.0)
Timestamp: Tue, 19 Jul 2011 20:21:24 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 33
Char: 39
Code: 0
URI: https://myserver/javascripts/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser does not support that code that will work in IE9. So upgrade your browser and ask your visitors to upgrade their browsers. Add a script to your website so that if someone try to access your website with IE8 or earlier You may redirect the user to a different version of the website.